# Creating Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate with just LambaExpression and comparison value

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I need to create a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, but all I have is a `LambaExpression` of the property to compare and the value to use for the comparison.

This is what the predicate would look like if I hard code it, and this is what I need to achieve but don't know how.

```
string comparisonValue = "something";

Expression<Func<Person, bool>> predicate = person => person.Name == comparisonValue;
```

I have the following:

```
LambdaExpression expression = PropertyExpression<Person>(t => t.Name);
```

Is there a way to generate the hard coded predicate like the above with just a property LambdaExpression and the value to compare?

I've tried using `LambdaExpression.Equal()`, but cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement this as follows.

```
Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> EqualToExpression<TSource, TValue>(
    Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> selectValue, TValue targetValue)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            selectValue.Body,
            Expression.Constant(targetValue)),
        selectValue.Parameters);
}
```

Use it as follows.

```
Expression<Func<Person, string>> selectName = p => p.Name;
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> compareName = EqualToExpression(selectName, "John");
```

Comment: Thanks you, now I understand... great answer.